# Parse different number of json objects in json array android

Tags: android, json

I am this json response from server.

```
{
    "Patient Data 1": [
        {
            "Name": "priya",
            "Postal_Code": "110025",
            "Email_Id": "priysa@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "Entered_Date": "8 Jul 2015",
            "EDD_Date": "15 Apr 2016"
        },
        {
            "Entered_Date": "06-08-2015",
            "Weight_log": "60"
        },
        {
            "Entered_Date": "27-09-2015",
            "Weight_log": "65"
        },
        {
            "Entered_Date": "28-09-2015",
            "Weight_log": "65"
        },
        {
            "Entered_Date": "8 Jul 2015",
            "Weight_log": "75"
        },
        {
            "Entered_Date": "8 Jul 2015",
            "Weight_log": "65"
        }
    ],
    "Patient Data 2": [
        {
            "Name": "priya",
            "Postal_Code": "110056",
            "Email_Id": "priya@yahoo.co.in"
        },
        {
            "Entered_Date": "8 Jul 2015",
            "EDD_Date": "15 Apr 2016"
        },
        {
            "Entered_Date": "8 Jun 2015",
            "Weight_log": "65"
        },
        {
            "Entered_Date": "8 Jun 2015",
            "Weight_log": "60"
        },
        {
            "Entered_Date": "8 Jul 2015",
            "Weight_log": "65"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to show a list view of patient having data "Name", "Postal_Code", "Email Id", "Entered_date", "EDD_Date" and a button in row item. So when click this button, I get again a list view of data "Entered_Date" and "Weight_Date".

I have parsed this data as below.

public void getPatientData(final String patientName){

```
    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Please wait..");
    dialog.show();

    final String BASE_URL = "http://spirantcommunication.com/andriod/grl/doctor_show.php?";
    final String NAME_PARAM = "name";

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(NAME_PARAM, patientName)
            .build();

    String url = uri.toString();

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null,

            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    dialog.dismiss();

                    int count = response.length();

                    try {
                        if (count == 1 && response.getJSONArray("Patient Data 1").
                                getJSONObject(0).getString("Message").equals("No Record Found for this Patient")){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Record for this patient", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (count >= 1 && response.getJSONArray("Patient Data 1").
                                getJSONObject(0).getString("Name").equalsIgnoreCase(patientName)){

                            List<PatientModel> list = new ArrayList<>();

                            ArrayList<WeightModel> weightModels = new ArrayList<>();
                            PatientModel patientModel = null;

                            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++){
                                try {
                                    JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("Patient Data " + i);
                                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = array.getJSONObject(0);
                                    JSONObject jsonObject2 = array.getJSONObject(1);

                                    String patientName = jsonObject1.getString("Name");
                                    String patientPostalCode = jsonObject1.getString("Postal_Code");
                                    String patientEmailId = jsonObject1.getString("Email_Id");
                                    String patientEnteredEddDate = jsonObject2.getString("Entered_Date");
                                    String patientEddDate = jsonObject2.getString("EDD_Date");

                                    Log.v("Patient Name", patientName);
                                    Log.v("Patient Postal Code", patientPostalCode);
                                    Log.v("Patient Email Id", patientEmailId);
                                    Log.v("Selected Edd Date", patientEnteredEddDate);
                                    Log.v("Edd Date", patientEddDate);

                                    patientModel = new PatientModel();
                                    patientModel.setPatientName(patientName);
                                    patientModel.setPatientPostalCode(patientPostalCode);
                                    patientModel.setPatientEmail(patientEmailId);
                                    patientModel.setPatientSelectedEddDate(patientEnteredEddDate);
                                    patientModel.setPatientEddDate(patientEddDate);


                                    for (int j = 2; j < array.length(); j++){

                                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(j);
                                        WeightModel weightModel = new WeightModel();
                                        weightModel.setSelectWeightDate(object.getString("Entered_Date"));
                                        weightModel.setWeightValue(object.getString("Weight_log"));
                                        weightModels.add(weightModel);
                                        patientModel.setWeightModels(weightModels);

                                        Log.v("Weight Entered Date", object.getString("Entered_Date"));
                                        Log.v("Weight Value", object.getString("Weight_log"));
                                    }
                                    list.add(patientModel);
                                }catch (JSONException e){
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            PatientRecordCustomAdapter adapter = new PatientRecordCustomAdapter(list, getApplicationContext());
                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    jsonObjectRequest.setTag(TAG);
    jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20 * 1000, 1, 1.0f));
    ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest, TAG);
}
```

And the model class that I have used is as

```
public class PatientModel {

    private String patientName;
    private String patientEmail;
    private String patientPostalCode;
    private String patientSelectedEddDate;
    private String patientEddDate;
    private ArrayList<WeightModel> weightModels = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getPatientName() {
        return patientName;
    }

    public void setPatientName(String patientName) {
        this.patientName = patientName;
    }

    public String getPatientEmail() {
        return patientEmail;
    }

    public void setPatientEmail(String patientEmail) {
        this.patientEmail = patientEmail;
    }

    public String getPatientPostalCode() {
        return patientPostalCode;
    }

    public void setPatientPostalCode(String patientPostalCode) {
        this.patientPostalCode = patientPostalCode;
    }

    public String getPatientSelectedEddDate() {
        return patientSelectedEddDate;
    }

    public void setPatientSelectedEddDate(String patientSelectedEddDate) {
        this.patientSelectedEddDate = patientSelectedEddDate;
    }

    public String getPatientEddDate() {
        return patientEddDate;
    }

    public void setPatientEddDate(String patientEddDate) {
        this.patientEddDate = patientEddDate;
    }

    public ArrayList<WeightModel> getWeightModels() {
        return weightModels;
    }

    public void setWeightModels(ArrayList<WeightModel> weightModels) {
        this.weightModels = weightModels;
    }

}
```

And the custom Adapter that I am using is as

public class PatientRecordCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

```
private List<PatientModel> data;
private Context context;

public PatientRecordCustomAdapter(List<PatientModel> data, Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_patient_record, parent, false);
    }

    TextView patientName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPatientName);
    patientName.setText("Patient Name: " + data.get(position).getPatientName());

    TextView patientPostalCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPostalCode);
    patientPostalCode.setText("Patient Postal Code: " + data.get(position).getPatientPostalCode());

    TextView patientEmailId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmailId);
    patientEmailId.setText("Patient Email Id: " + data.get(position).getPatientEmail());

    TextView selectedEddDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSelectedEddDate);
    selectedEddDate.setText("Patient Selected Edd Date: " + data.get(position).getPatientSelectedEddDate());

    TextView eddDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvEdd);
    eddDate.setText("Patient Edd Date: " + data.get(position).getPatientEddDate());

    ArrayList<WeightModel> list = data.get(position).getWeightModels();
    int size = list.size();

    Log.v("Size", String.valueOf(size));

    for (WeightModel model1 : list){
        Log.v("Selected Weight Date", model1.getSelectWeightDate());
        Log.v("Select Weight Value", model1.getWeightValue());
    }

    Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, CheckWeightDataActivity.class);
            // intent.putExtra("Weight List", (ArrayList<WeightModel>) weightData);
            //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            //context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

}

But I am getting this log cat for "Entered_Date" and "Weight_log" as

```
06-09 15:26:13.398  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Size﹕ 8
06-09 15:26:13.398  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 06-08-2015
06-09 15:26:13.398  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 60
06-09 15:26:13.398  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 27-09-2015
06-09 15:26:13.398  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 65
06-09 15:26:13.398  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 28-09-2015
06-09 15:26:13.398  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 65
06-09 15:26:13.398  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 8 Jul 2015
06-09 15:26:13.398  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 75
06-09 15:26:13.398  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 8 Jul 2015
06-09 15:26:13.398  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 65
06-09 15:26:13.398  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 8 Jun 2015
06-09 15:26:13.398  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 65
06-09 15:26:13.398  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 8 Jun 2015
06-09 15:26:13.399  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 60
06-09 15:26:13.399  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 8 Jul 2015
06-09 15:26:13.399  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 65
06-09 15:26:13.410  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Size﹕ 8
06-09 15:26:13.410  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 06-08-2015
06-09 15:26:13.410  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 60
06-09 15:26:13.410  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 27-09-2015
06-09 15:26:13.410  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 65
06-09 15:26:13.410  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 28-09-2015
06-09 15:26:13.410  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 65
06-09 15:26:13.410  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 8 Jul 2015
06-09 15:26:13.410  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 75
06-09 15:26:13.410  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 8 Jul 2015
06-09 15:26:13.410  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 65
06-09 15:26:13.410  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 8 Jun 2015
06-09 15:26:13.410  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 65
06-09 15:26:13.410  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 8 Jun 2015
06-09 15:26:13.410  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 60
06-09 15:26:13.410  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 8 Jul 2015
06-09 15:26:13.410  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 65
06-09 15:26:13.415  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Size﹕ 8
06-09 15:26:13.415  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 06-08-2015
06-09 15:26:13.415  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 60
06-09 15:26:13.415  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 27-09-2015
06-09 15:26:13.415  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 65
06-09 15:26:13.415  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 28-09-2015
06-09 15:26:13.415  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 65
06-09 15:26:13.415  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 8 Jul 2015
06-09 15:26:13.415  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 75
06-09 15:26:13.415  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 8 Jul 2015
06-09 15:26:13.415  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 65
06-09 15:26:13.415  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 8 Jun 2015
06-09 15:26:13.415  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 65
06-09 15:26:13.415  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 8 Jun 2015
06-09 15:26:13.415  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 60
06-09 15:26:13.415  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 8 Jul 2015
06-09 15:26:13.415  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 65
06-09 15:26:13.425  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Size﹕ 8
06-09 15:26:13.425  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 06-08-2015
06-09 15:26:13.425  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 60
06-09 15:26:13.425  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 27-09-2015
06-09 15:26:13.425  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 65
06-09 15:26:13.425  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 28-09-2015
06-09 15:26:13.425  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 65
06-09 15:26:13.425  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 8 Jul 2015
06-09 15:26:13.425  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 75
06-09 15:26:13.425  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 8 Jul 2015
06-09 15:26:13.425  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 65
06-09 15:26:13.425  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 8 Jun 2015
06-09 15:26:13.425  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 65
06-09 15:26:13.425  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 8 Jun 2015
06-09 15:26:13.425  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 60
06-09 15:26:13.425  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Selected Weight Date﹕ 8 Jul 2015
06-09 15:26:13.425  24277-24277/com.spirant.grl V/Select Weight Value﹕ 65
```

I am getting four lists rather than two. Please help me.

Comment: I think you consider reformatting json first. If you format json right way then you can easily parse json to your models by using Gson.

Comment: @AhmadNawaz what do you mean? That **structure** of this json is fu* up? ... then I agree with you ...

Comment: @Ahmad Nawaz can you give me example?

Comment: Array of Patient Objects and inside Patient Object Array of WeightModel. like that.

Comment: `[ { "patient_info": { "name" : "Ździcho", "surname": "Kowalski", "maybe_some_id" :1 }, "patient_entries" : [ { ... } , { ... } ]  }, { "patient_info": { "name" : "Juzio", "surname": "Schmit", "maybe_some_id" : 2 }, "patient_entries" : [ { ... }, { ... }, { ... } ]  }]`

Comment: @Selvin Yes I mean structure of json.

Answer (score 0):

First of All Change structure of Your json according to your requirement. like following.

```
[
    {
        "Name": "priya",
        "Postal_Code": "110056",
        "Email_Id": "priya@yahoo.co.in",
        "weightModels": [
            {
                "Entered_Date": "8Jul2015",
                "EDD_Date": "15Apr2016"
            },
            {
                "Entered_Date": "8Jun2015",
                "Weight_log": "65"
            },
            {
                "Entered_Date": "8Jun2015",
                "Weight_log": "60"
            },
            {
                "Entered_Date": "8Jul2015",
                "Weight_log": "65"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "priya",
        "Postal_Code": "110056",
        "Email_Id": "priya@yahoo.co.in",
        "weightModels": [
            {
                "Entered_Date": "8Jul2015",
                "EDD_Date": "15Apr2016"
            },
            {
                "Entered_Date": "8Jun2015",
                "Weight_log": "65"
            },
            {
                "Entered_Date": "8Jun2015",
                "Weight_log": "60"
            },
            {
                "Entered_Date": "8Jul2015",
                "Weight_log": "65"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Then Simple parse with `Gson`

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.lenght();i++){
   PatientModel patient = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.get(i),PatientModel.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have double the results you were expecting then your loops are likely to be wrong.

Start by loggin the "array.length()" and "count" values to see if they have the expected values, if the size is more then you expected then you have found the issue.

Otherwise debug your code step by step (add breakpoints) and you will see more clearly where it goes wrong, much easier then staring at a couple pages of code